# "First aid kit" or "medicine box" for home use?

Tags: medical, professions, generic-term

What term is more widespread and suitable when we speak about box with medicines you keep **at home** on a regular basis? Every family has such box, where you store necessary medicines, bandages, syringes and etc.
I don't mean kits which are used in hiking, trekking, and other sport activities, as well as bags used by professionals (e.g. emergency physicians). I know "first aid kit" is a must here. 
But what if we speak about more extended (not only first aid) kit ?

Comment: You would have a lot of confusion in the US as to whether you're talking about the *medicine cabinet* (or *medicine chest*) behind the mirror in the bathroom or something else.  As to medicines, they're stored in a kitchen cabinet, bandages are stored everywhere except where you can find one when you need it, and I keep the syringes hidden under the false drawer bottom in my sock drawer.

Comment: An [emergency medical box](http://www.mtmmedical.com/emergency_medical_box.htm) seems very similar to a "first aid kit".

Answer (score 3):

**There seems to be a lot of regional differences, and no single answer. It may also change from household to household within a region.**

In Australia, **first aid kit** is used for something you take with you or keep at home or at the office/workplace. I've never heard *medicine box*, but it might be used in other English speaking countries, although I doubt it.

**Medicine cabinet** is used also, but refers to a glass-fronted cabinet above the sink in a bathroom that contains medications and toiletries. Others have suggested *medicine cabinet* can also refer to a wooden box, possibly mounted on the wall, but without a glass front.

Others have suggested **medicine chest** and **medicine cupboard**.

Comment: And what about **medicine chest**? Is it in use?

Comment: In England, the general purpose, mirrored, fancy-looking box on the wall is a bathroom cabinet not a medicine cabinet. A medicine cabinet would be a plain-looking, wooden box with a cross on the front. It wouldn't have any glass, possibly mounted on the wall and probably with a lock. It would contain first-aid items and similar.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I doubt that the position is as settled and universal as you suggest. It is one of those things for which different families will have different names. Ours is high-up in the kitchen and we call it the *medicine cupboard*. but my wife is Chinese - so we do have rather a lot of medicines, both ancient herbal remedies as well as things from the pharmacy.

Comment: The US usage generally mirrors the Australian, at least in my area.  *Medicine chest* seems more like something a doctor or perhaps a survivalist might have, although the a more common term is "field hospital kit".

Comment: So, _first aid kit_ is quite common and can be used both for survivalist expeditions/activities and for home use. Am I correct?

Comment: I think *first aid kit* is common, and some people would have them at home. The problem is you wouldn’t store personal medications in them, only something generic like mild pain tablets. I think you’re going to need one of the terms that start with *medicine*, ending in *chest*, *cupboard* or *cabinet*. But there is no standard here.